# change bash shortcut keys such as Ctrl-C?

Tags: linux, bash, inputrc

I am using Kubuntu 10.04. I would like to change some of the standard shortcut keys for bash (terminal).

Here are the shortcuts I would like to set up:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> to copy the selected text in
  the terminal to the clipboard.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> to paste from the clipboard 
  into the terminal.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd> to undo the editing on the current line in the terminal.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> (or even better,  <kbd>Super</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>) to terminate the command.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd> (or <kbd>Super</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd>) to be the     background command.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> (or <kbd>Super</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd>) to be   the literal insert command (or whatever <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>z</kbd> did before).

How do I make these changes?

BTW, I like the way the terminal works on OS X. The use of the command key makes all the copy/paste commands very consistent (unlike many other things in OS X).

P.S. I read the bash man page and it didn't help. It gave me ideas, but I need specific examples for the above combinations. Thanks.

Comment: some of these "shortcuts" can not be "implemented" in bash, but have to be put onto the terminal itself (xterm, gnome-terminal, konsole etc).. eg "selected text", "clipboard"

Comment: This work for me: https://superuser.com/a/1726410/1701302 Thank you the author.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Those aren't features of bash, they're features of the terminal driver. As such, they're specified by `stty(1)`.

```
$ stty -a
speed 38400 baud; rows 24; columns 80; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = M-^?; eol2 = M-^?;
swtch = M-^?; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R; werase = ^W;
lnext = ^V; flush = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd cs8 hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon -ixoff
-iuclc ixany imaxbel iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt
echoctl echoke
```

Comment: OK. Thanks for the clue. Now, I'd still like to accomplish my goal. And I also know that inputrc can remap Ctrl-C. But I really don't care how I do it, I just want to know to how remap these shortcuts in a terminal.

Comment: Here's the "fish":
stty intr \^k
(where the terminate command, formerly Ctrl-C now becomes Ctrl-K, K can be any alpha key)
No one "gave me that fish". I worked hard to find it on my own. So preaching with proverbs makes you look like a jerk, IMO.

Comment: How can you remap it to Ctrl+Shift+C?

Comment: In my opinion, this is very stty way to doing it.

Answer (score 12):

This is **almost** completely solved now. Part of the solution was first brought to my attention by MTK358 over at https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/change-bash-shortcut-keys-such-as-ctrl-c-818170/. He pointed out the (rather obvious, much to my embarrassment) fact that the copy and paste shortcut keys can easily be changed by the menu settings of konsole. Once I saw this, it took about 1 minute to set up Ctrl-C and Ctrl-V to copy and paste with the terminal.

The other part of the solution should have been clear from the stty man page, but it wasn't (to me). I ended up just experimenting based on various clues, such as those posted above.

I decided which non-numeric key I wanted to replace Ctrl-C as the terminate command. (I used "k"). I never did find any info about how to convey a shift modifier to stty, so I gave up on that. With that decided, all I had to do was enter the following on the command line:

**stty intr ^k**

I verified that everything worked as desired.

Now I just had to place the single command above (stty intr ^k) in a startup script. I'm not sure which one is the "proper" one. I'd like this change to be system wide and permanent.

Any suggestions as to which script I should place the command in?

And finally, as to the preachy replies, they are unnecessary and unhelpful.

Comment: Did you ever determine what the "right" startup script to use is, or a better way to do this? I'm struggling with this same problem (your original question). But while I can make 'stty intr \^k' bind ctrl-k, it isn't unbinding ctrl-c and neither 'stty intr undef' nor 'stty intr = ^-' do it, ctrl-c still sends an interupt. And 'stty -a' never shows any change I've made.

Comment: @EricS, see my answer below.. spoiler: put it in your .bashrc

Answer (score 6):

Some of thse can be set using the normal KDE keyboard shortcut mechanism. In Konsole's "Settings" menu, click on "Configure Shortcuts", and you'll get a dialog which you can use to change the key bindings for the functions which are handled by KDE. That will allow you to remap Ctrl+C to copy and Ctrl+V to paste - but keep in mind that once you do that, those key sequences will no longer be passed through to the terminal, so you won't be able to use Ctrl+C to interrupt a program, for example.

Other functions are controlled by the `readline` library, which you can configure by editing the file `~/.inputrc`. To get Ctrl+Z to revert any edits made on the current line, you'd want to add

```
C-z: revert-line
```

but that key sequence is probably already trapped by the terminal, so you might have to use `stty` to unbind it before it'll work. First look for `^Z` in the output of `stty -a` (as shown in Ignacio's answer) and then, for example, if it shows up in `susp = ^Z`, run

```
stty susp ^-
```

to unbind that key mapping.

The other changes you're asking about would have to be done with `stty` as Ignacio says, since those are terminal functions, but I'm not sure exactly how. The issue is that I don't know whether the terminal recognizes Shift, or if it does, how to convey that information to `stty`.

Answer (score 6):

I run Ubuntu and changed the shortcut for Copy from the default <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to the more normal and simple <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. This however made me run into problem not being able to send the interrupt command **^C**.

Thanks to [@Paul answer](https://superuser.com/a/160984/517358) I found running the command

```
tty intr \^k
```

Will allow me to send the interrupt command using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>. However this command needed to be run every time I open the terminal which is a hassle (just like he mentioned himself).

With a little bit of further research (googling ) [I found how to execute a command each time the terminal is opened (in Ubuntu anyway)](https://askubuntu.com/q/679621/896450).

Thus, finally running the following command **(once)** (in Ubuntu 18.04 and likely more) will give the expected behavior everytime.

```
echo $'# Make Ctrl+K interrupt command in terminal\nstty intr \^k\n' >> ~/.bashrc
```

Finally, it's worth to mention that you must not use the <kbd>K</kbd> button. You may exchange the **k** letter in all commands above to any letter key of your choice.

Comment: The \ before ^k may be unnecessary

Answer (score 2):

Bash uses `emacs` or `vi` mode on the command line. It has no concept of "selection" or "clipboard". It uses things like a "kill buffer" and "point", "mark", "word", "line", "kill" and "yank", etc.

Trying to shoehorn GUI-style functionality into it will be frustrating at best and won't work fully. You will have to try to combine functions of `stty`, `readline` and your terminal (presumably `Terminal.app` for you). You will need to remap functions such as `intr`, `susp`, `lnext`, etc., so you can still use their features.

I strongly recommend against such radical modifications. It just wasn't designed to do what you want.

When in Rome...

Comment: Dave, for a system that works just like OS X, might I suggest you use OS X? As Dennis hinted, even if you can get it to work, you'll be pretty hobbled when you log in as anything but you on your own machine.

Comment: I can't vouch for the other commands but copy and paste make perfect sense in a command window and are very handy. I use them constantly to copy and paste between other windows and the console, and have done so for many years. Shift-Ctrl-C and Shift-Ctrl-V work this way for Konsole out of the box. And though I've done this every day for years, I inevitably forget and hit Ctrl-c in Konsole. Personally, I'm ready to stop applying the "when in Rome" adage and remap them to work like virtually EVERY other application in existence.

Answer (score 2):

I reckon this is an old post, but the following can be handy.

I am using the Mate Terminal on Ubuntu 18.04. At the GUI interface of the Mate Terminal it is possible to configure the keyboard shortcuts Crtl+C for copy, and Ctrl-V for paste. When doing that, the Mate Terminal *automatically* swaps the intr function to the shortcut shift-crtl-c, so it works just out of the box.

Another hint is that we can use the mouse for smart copy/paste operations. When right-clicking in any application, not only for terminal, it will copy the selected text *automatically*, and the paste function can be done with the middle button. Below you can find more information on that.

https://www.howtogeek.com/440558/how-to-copy-and-paste-text-at-linuxs-bash-shell/

Comment: Thanks, this is the only place I've found about auto-remapping *intr* to Ctrl+Shift+C. Works fine with default (Gnome) Terminal in Linux Mint 20 Cinnamon. No need to mess with .bashrc, no need to invent a new key combination.

Answer (score 2):

Source: https://superuser.com/a/1726410/1701302

### For BASH

Add to your `~/.bashrc` the follow command:

```
bind '"\C-f": "\C-a date \C-j"' # CTRL+F
```

---

### For ZSH

Add to your `~/.zshrc` the follow command:

```sh
bindkey -s "\C-f" "\C-a date \C-j" # CTRL+F
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18900803/persistent-stty-settings, I put `stty intr ^D` in my .bashrc (or .profile) and it worked on a new konsole window. I also set the Copy shortcut to Ctrl-C in the Konsole Shortcuts Settings. Ctrl-Z can be set in .inputrc as @David Z stated.

Answer (score 0):

For **BASH**: Add edit your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_aliases`

For **ZSH**: Edit your `~/.zshrc`

And add the follow command:

```sh
# For bash
bind '"\C-f": "php -v"' ## only type text, NO RUN
bind '"\C-f": "\C-a php -v \C-j"' ## run php -v command

# For ZSH
bindkey -s "\C-f" "php -v" ## only type text, NO RUN
bindkey -s "\C-f" "\C-a php -v \C-j" ## run php -v command
```

When you press `CTRL`+`F` will appear `php -v` inline.

For a valid command, use like this:

```sh
# For BASH
bind '"\C-f": "\C-a date \C-j"'

# For ZSH
bindkey -s "\C-f" "\C-a date \C-j"
```

When you press `CTRL`+`F` will appear the current time inline like:

```sh
ter 14 jun 2022 09:43:19 -03
```

#### Resume:

```sh
## For BASH
# Add to your ~/.bashrc or ~/.bash_aliases the follow command:
bind '"\C-f": "\C-a YOUR_COMMAND \C-j"'

# Example: 
bind '"\C-f": "\C-a echo $(date) \C-j"' # CTRL+F run YOUR_COMMAND
####

## For ZSH
# Add to your ~/.zshrc the follow command:
bindkey -s "\C-f" "\C-a YOUR_COMMAND \C-j"

# Example: 
bindkey -s "\C-f" "\C-a date \C-j" # CTRL+F
```